# Joomla jUpgrade stops at "Migrating undefined"

Tags: joomla

I'm trying to use jUpgrade to migrate a Joomla 1.5.26 installation to 2.5.

It is failing at:

> Upgrading progress...
>   Migrating undefined

It never proceeds from here.

Checking the error log in `/administrator`, I see:

> PHP Warning:  Module 'PDO' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
>   PHP Warning:  Module 'pdo_mysql' already loaded in Unknown on line 0

Comment: If you don't receive an answer to your Joomla question here, you might ask it over at this StackExchange Area51 site:  http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/34294/joomla

Comment: Thanks @dan, but the questions there are locked it seems.

Comment: Looks like the [Joomla site](http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions) is in Beta now, let me know if you'd like this migrated over there.

Answer (score 2):

The process of migrating Joomla 1.5 to 2.5 is often a complex process, depending on what extensions you have on your current website. It's seldom a one-click process.

First of all, **make sure you have a complete backup of your site** (I recommend [Akeeba Backup](https://www.akeebabackup.com/products/akeeba-backup.html))

There are several ways to do the migration, and several tools that claim to be a one-click solution. As you see, that doesn't always turn out to be true. I'm going to list a couple of alternatives, but first keep in mind the following:

1. Your current template will probably not work with Joomla 2.5. You'll have to:

   - modify it to make it compatible
   - download a new version from the template provider (if available)
   - use a different template
2. You'll have to look for an upgraded version of most of your extensions.
3. Some of your extensions might not be available for Joomla 2.5, and you'll have to look for an alternative extension with similar functionality.

*(on a side note: Joomla 2.5 has a planned [End Of Life](http://docs.joomla.org/What_version_of_Joomla!_should_you_use%3F#Joomla.21_CMS_versions) in a few months, you might want to consider upgrading to Joomla 3.)*

#### Option 1: Build a new site

Taking into account the points above, you might be better of creating a completely new site. Start with a clean Joomla 2.5 (or 3) installation. Then use [J2XML](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/migration-a-conversion/data-import-a-export/12816) to transfer your articles (with images), categories, menus and users. This will give you a kickstart, and the advantage is that you have a very clean Joomla installation. Install a new template and configure the site as needed.

#### Option 2: Try other migration tools

If jUpgrade fails, there's a list of different tools for Joomla migration at [JED](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/migration-a-conversion/joomla-migration). You might have better luck with another migration tool. As long as you work on a copy of your site, there's nothing wrong with testing different solutions (except it might be time consuming).